# Same Navbar without collapse

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a navbar with a logo, download app button, sliding in menu(as u can see in image)
[image]

But when the width is less than 768 pixels, I want the navbar to appear same like the wider screen view.But it is appearing like this
[image]

Navbar with sliding menu:

[image]

I have tried it in many ways but could not get it. 
My code http://jsbin.com/neyenanevu/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: we cant see the code sire.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I have given other link for code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPD. You can find all the fragments of the `bootstrap.css` which mention the `navbar` and `@media (min-width: 768px)` at the same time.

Try to use:

```
.navbar-left {
  float: left !important;
}
.navbar-right {
  float: right !important;
  margin-right: -15px;
}
.navbar-right ~ .navbar-right {
  margin-right: 0;
}
.navbar-nav {
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
}
.navbar-nav > li {
  float: left;
}
.navbar-nav > li > a {
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}
```

http://jsbin.com/nenuquq/edit?html,css,js,output

---

You can set up the breakpoint at which the navbar becomes collapsed:

1. In the [Grid system](http://www.getbootstrap.sk/customize/#grid-system) set the field `@grid-float-breakpoint` value as you need. For example, zero.
2. Click the `Compile and Download` button at the bottom of the page.
3. Extract the files `bootstrap.css` and  `bootstrap.min.css` from the resulting archive. Use them instead of the standard files `bootstrap.css` and `bootstrap.min.css` on your site.
4. Tune your Navbar as you want. It will be the same at any screen width.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It works but I don't want to use custom bootstrap I have same bootstrap linked to all files. So if i change now, everything gets messed up!

Comment: @SriharshaNutalapati Oh, I see. Try to use: `.navbar-left {
  float: left !important;
}
.navbar-right {
  float: right !important;
}`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @SriharshaNutalapati You can find all the fragments of the `bootstrap.css` which mention the `navbar` and `@media (min-width: 768px)` at the same time.

Comment: I have tried it, but the download button and menu are appearing one below other

Comment: @SriharshaNutalapati Try `.navbar-left {
  float: left !important;
}
.navbar-right {
  float: right !important;
  margin-right: -15px;
}
.navbar-right ~ .navbar-right {
  margin-right: 0;
}
.navbar-nav {
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
}
.navbar-nav > li {
  float: left;
}
.navbar-nav > li > a {
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}`. I've updated my answer.